# How can I page through a list of Twilio Fax Resources?

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

I'm using the Twilio Rest API and I'm trying to get a list of faxes.

```
var faxes = FaxResource.Read();
```

This returns a ResourceSet but I don't understand how the pagination is supposed to work. I came across an article by Twilio that indicated that due to performance reasons they did away with "normal/understandable" pagination. That's great, the reasons they gave made sense etc., but I'm no further ahead in understanding that which has replaced it.

Ultimately, I'm trying to get a paged list of faxes and bind it to a jquery.DataTables table. I can get the entire list of faxes send and bind it, but I don't want to retrieve hundreds/thousands+ of records when in reality I'm only going to display a handful at a time.
If I understand correctly, at least part of this will be problematic (the pager on the DataTable allows for jumping to arbitrary pages, which I believe is not possible anymore with any of the Twilio Resource lists. (Actually, that's easily remedied by changing the DataTable to "simple" which only shows the Previous/Next buttons).

Can anybody provide some guidance (perhaps a small code snippet) on how to paginate a Resource list (or if there are some differences across the different Resources, specifically a FaxResource list)?

Typical paging requirements apply:

- I need to know the full count of records that match my filter (it may be that I'm not filtering at all, so full count)
- I want to get only a "page" of records at a time - equal to the number of records that I will display in one page of my table
- I need to (obviously) page through the full list

Answer (score 0):

I guess the question is not only about pagination but filtering as well. Based on the doc of Twilio, FaxResource.Read() takes several parameters:

```
public static ResourceSet<FaxResource> Read(string from = null, string to = null, DateTime? dateCreatedOnOrBefore = null, DateTime? dateCreatedAfter = null, int? pageSize = null, long? limit = null, ITwilioRestClient client = null);
```

So you can do something like this:

```
var faxes = FaxResource.Read(to: "yourFaxNumber", dateCreatedAfter: DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
```